# Option refresh after insert data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Listed the data like this:

```
    <select class="custom-select col-md-10" id="routeList" size="8">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <?php
        include( '../cnn.php' );
        $query= $db_con->query( "select routeName, id from tbroutes order by routeName" );
        $routes= $query->fetchAll();
        foreach ( $routes as $route) {
           echo "<option value=\"" . $route[ 'id' ] . "\">" . $route[ 'routeName' ] . "</option>";
       }
       ?>
   </select>
```

I have a text input and button. Button clicked adding a new route to the database.

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
        var route = $('#textRoute').val();
        $.post("addRoute.php",{
            route: route
        }, function(addRoute){});
    });
```

**addRoute.php**

```
<?php
if ( $_POST ) {
    $route = $_POST[ 'route' ];
    include "../cnn.php";

    $query = $db_con->query( "insert into tbroutes (routeName) values ('$route')", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
} else {
    header( "location:index.php" );
}
?>
```

I want to do is to refresh the options (re-list) without refreshing the page after insert a new route.

I don't know much about Ajax, can you help me?

Comment: update list after adding data in db? user $.post success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your PHP script return the new ID inserted into the database.

```
if ( $_POST ) {
    $route = $_POST[ 'route' ];
    include "../cnn.php";

    //$query = $db_con->query( "insert into tbroutes (routeName) values ('$route')", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    //THIS IS AT RISK FOR SQL INJECTION, safer to use the following:

    $query = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbroutes (routeName) VALUES (?)");
    $query->execute([$route]);
    //Notice that I capitalize non-variable words in the query, this makes it easier to read

    echo json_encode(["success" => true, "uid" => $db_con->lastInsertId(), "route" => $route]); //assuming your using PDO

} else {
    echo json_encode(["success" => false]);
}
```

(Note, your `header( "location:index.php" );` won't really do anything here because it is loaded by ajax.)

I'm also returning if the insert was a success or not. I also return the route if the insert was successful, this is my personal preferance as I think it's easier to work with return data rather than using data from different places.

I return the data as a JSON string because that's an extremely easy way to work with the data in Javascript.

Now, capture the response in your ajax call

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
    var route = $('#textRoute').val();
    $.post("addRoute.php",{
        route: route
    }, function(addRoute){
        addRoute = JSON.parse(addRoute); //this may or may not be necessary, depending on your environment
        if(addRoute.success) {
            $('#routeList').append(
                $('<option>', {value: addRoute.uid, text: addRoute.route})
            );
        } else {
            //failed to insert
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But there is a problem this code, data insert is success, although it enters the else block.

Comment: @aliitascan Right above `if(addRoute.success)` can you do `console.log(addRoute)` and tell me what the output is on the console?

Comment: {"success":true,"uid":"29","route":"test"}. very interesting. Let me try on secret tab.

Comment: result is the same on secret tab

Comment: @aliitascan Replace `console.log(addRoute)` with `addRoute = JSON.parse(addRoute);` - I think the problem is that javascript is reading it as a string and not an object.